# Why does my variable appear to be static?

Tags: r

The `j` variable in my code below appears to be static, as it is never re-set to 0 by `j <- 0`.  The output for my code is supposed to look like this:

```
   i   j
1 30  932
2 29  711
3 28  475
4 27  338
5 26  586
6 25  463
```

but it currently looks like this:

```
   i    j
1 30  932
2 29 1643
3 28 2118
4 27 2456
5 26 3042
6 25 3505
```

I would assume that j should get reset to 0 on each iteration of `i in id` but this is not happening. Here is the code:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:322){

#list of all files in target directory
files = dir(directory, full.names = T)

# represent a single file as a data frame
file.frame <- data.frame();

# one row of the output frame
result.frame.row <- data.frame();

# complete output frame
result.frame <- data.frame();


for(i in id){
    # get all data from the specified csv
    file.frame <- rbind(file.frame, read.csv(files[i])) 

    j <- 0
    for (k in 1:nrow(file.frame)){
        if (!is.na(file.frame$sulfate[k]) && !is.na(file.frame$nitrate[k])){
            j <- j + 1
        }   
    }
    result.frame.row <- cbind(i, j)
    result.frame <- rbind(result.frame, result.frame.row)
}

result.frame
}
```

EDIT: Here is a bare-bones implementation of the function without references to files. It does NOT have the same behavior as the function above (i.e., it works correctly).

```
complete <- function(id){

result.frame.row <- data.frame()
result.frame <- data.frame()

for(i in id){    
    j <- 0

    for (k in 1:5){
        if (TRUE){
            j <- j + 1
        }   
    }

    result.frame.row <- cbind(j)
    result.frame <- rbind(result.frame, result.frame.row)    
}

result.frame

}
```

Comment: How sure are you this is true? Can you remove references to files and such to make it something that anyone can run and reproduce the results?

Comment: Based on the edit, it is impossible for anyone to determine what is wrong with your code (if anything!).  Please create a minimum reproducible example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The fact that your minimal sample works, makes me either think your expectations we wrong on the first chunk of code, or that there was some typo or misunderstanding on your end. If the problem is not reproducible, then we can't help you. It's not like you were doing anything unusual.

Comment: This is my guess: 
file.frame <- rbind(file.frame, read.csv(files[i])) 
part is adding to file.frame, and not replacing it. and so the loop is repeating previous + new and not just new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough points for a comment - so it gets to look like an answer:

Do you really mean `file.frame <- rbind(file.frame, read.csv(files[i]))`? Because if you do, each iteration of `for (k in 1:nrow(file.frame)){...` gets to repeat everything from the previous iteration - including incrementing `j` to the previous value before starting on new data/rows.

Try `file.frame <- read.csv(files[i])` and see if you get what you're expecting.